# How is it possible that java.lang.Object is implemented in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

According to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2), `java.lang.Object` is the root of Java's inheritance hierarchy. Unlike C++ or Objective-C, programmers cannot specify their own root superclasses. Because of this, I figured it was impossible to actually define `java.lang.Object` in Java itself. To my surprise, I found that OpenJDK indeed has [a concrete implementation of `java.lang.Object`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java).

I wanted to see if it was possible to compile and run my own version of `java.lang.Object` with JDK/JRE 1.8, so I wrote this as `Object.java`:

```java
package java.lang;
public class Object {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world from custom java.lang.Object!");
    }
}
```

It compiled just fine with `javac`, but if I try to execute the classfile via `java -cp . java.lang.Object`, the JVM errors out with this message:

```
Error: Main method not found in class java.lang.Object, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

which suggests that the JVM is using the stock `java.lang.Object` instead of the `Object.class` in the classpath.

Is it possible to define `java.lang.Object` in Java as an end user? What is going on under the hood? I see two possibilities:

- The JVM loads a real `Object.class` file that was compiled from the OpenJDK's `Object.java`. If this is the case, does the compiler do something special to prevent the classfile from specifying itself as the superclass?
- `java.lang.Object`'s implementation is intrinsic to the JVM. If this is the case, why is there an `Object.java` in OpenJDK?

Comment: There is a bootstrap class loader written in native code which loads classes such as `Object` and `ClassLoader`. Your `java.lang.Object` class is visible to a descendant class loader so the one visible to the bootstrap class loader (i.e. the real `java.lang.Object`) is always chosen first (they have the same FQN). This is due to parent-first delegation.

Comment: When I tried to run my own `java.lang.Object` in JDK 11, I got error: `package exists in another module: java.base`

Comment: @Slaw I just don't understand how the "real" `java.lang.Object` is written in the same version of Java that it defines `Object` for.

Comment: Bootstrapping. It's the same general concept that allows Java to be compiled by a compiler which itself is written in Java—the first compiler could not be written in Java. The JVM is written in native (i.e non-Java) code and can thus bootstrap classes such as `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: @Slaw So does the JVM load a real `Object.class` file, or is this implementation intrinsic? If it is intrinsic, why is there an `Object.java`? If there is a classfile, wouldn't it need to have special support from the compiler so that it doesn't specify itself as the superclass?

Comment: Yes, there's a real `Object.class` file. When you compile your code it is using the _compiled classes_ of the JDK as a library (i.e. you have a reference to `Object.class` not `Object.java`). And the compiler is running on an already compiled JDK, so it has access to `Object.class` as well. And both the JVM and the compiler are aware of the specification they respectively implement.

Comment: I would particularly listen to apangin and Holger in their answers. The former knows a lot about the JVM (at least the HotSpot implementation). And the latter is quite knowledgeable about Java as well. I at least consider them two of the leading experts on Java and the JVM who are active on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement `java.lang.Object` in Java and the actual class you’re using has been indeed created from the `Object.java` file that ships with the JDK.

The Java® Language Specification says in [Chapter 8. Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html):

> Each class except `Object` is an extension of (that is, a subclass of) a single existing class ([§8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)) and may implement interfaces ([§8.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5)).

So the absence of supertypes for `Object` is fixed in the language.

You can use the source code of your experiment and try to add an `extends` or `implements` clause and see that the compiler will reject it.

When you compile the class `java.lang.Object`, the resulting class file will be the only one that has no supertype. See The Java® Virtual Machine Specification, [§4.1., The ClassFile Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-F):

> super_class
>
> For a class, the value of the `super_class` item either must be zero or must be a valid index into the `constant_pool` table. If the value of the `super_class` item is nonzero, the `constant_pool` entry at that index must be a `CONSTANT_Class_info` structure representing the direct superclass of the class defined by this `class` file. Neither the direct superclass nor any of its superclasses may have the `ACC_FINAL` flag set in the `access_flags` item of its `ClassFile` structure.
>
> If the value of the `super_class` item is zero, then this `class` file must represent the class `Object`, the only class or interface without a direct superclass.
>
> For an interface, the value of the `super_class` item must always be a valid index into the `constant_pool` table. The `constant_pool` entry at that index must be a `CONSTANT_Class_info` structure representing the class `Object`.

So even interfaces have an entry for the superclass in the class file (pointing to `Object`) and the class file for `java.lang.Object` is the only one with a zero entry for the super class.

---

When you try to load your version of the `Object` class at runtime, you stumble across the fact that you can’t load classes of the `java.lang` package (or any class whose qualified name starts with `java.`) through the class path in general.

Prior to Java 9, you would have to set up the [*bootstrap class path*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABHDABI) to include your version. Starting with Java 9, [the class `java.lang.Object` must belong to the `java.base` module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3-310), which is loaded in an implementation specific manner. You’d have to use the [`--patch-module`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Patching-module-content) option to inject your own version.

But you have to be careful with what you write into your own version. There are a lot of expectations by other classes and the environment and not meeting them can break it (badly).

[JLS, §4.3.2. The Class Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2) lists the expected methods and links to other chapters that define special language semantics for some of them.

Answer (score 6):

You *can* modify `java.lang.Object` (e.g. by adding `public static void main()` method), but in order to be loaded and used by the JVM, the modified class needs to be added to the bootstrap class path.

On JDK 8 this can be done with

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:<path>
```

On JDK 9+ this requires patching `java.base` module:

```
java --patch-module java.base=<path>
```

When the JVM starts, it loads `java.lang.Object` by the bootstrap class loader just like any other class, so `java.lang.Object` with the added `main` method can be actually executed:

```
$ java -Xbootclasspath/p:. java.lang.Object
Hello world from custom java.lang.Object!
```

However, if you try to remove existing `java.lang.Object` methods, add new virtual methods, add fields or otherwise change the existing layout - this won't work. Most likely, the JVM will just crash with the fatal error.

This is because the JVM expects `java.lang.Object` to have the known layout. There are hard-coded offsets in the JVM source code, references to the exiting methods, etc. The same is true for other intrinsic classes like `java.lang.String`, `java.lang.Class`, `java.lang.ref.Reference` and similar.

As to Object's superclass, there is an exception explicitly described in [JVM Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1):

> If the value of the super_class item is zero, then this class file
> must represent the class Object, the only class or interface without a
> direct superclass.

Both Java compiler and the JVM know about this exception, and enforce this rule when [compiling](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/796c9fa50850/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/TypeEnter.java#l693) `Object.java` and when [loading](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/796c9fa50850/src/hotspot/share/classfile/classFileParser.cpp#l4003) `Object.class`.

Answer (score 3):

That's a really cool experiment.
But this is how Java works

1. Since every class in Java has to extend `java.lang.Object`, your custom `Object` class also extends that.
2. To load any class, Java needs to load it's parent classes. So when Java tries to run the `main()` method inside your custom `Object` class, it loads the real `java.lang.Object` class.
3. As soon as real `java.lang.Object` class is loaded, JVM tries to run the `main()` method of that class. Since it doesn't exist, your application fails with.

Comment: I figured that is what was going on, but this doesn't answer my question. I don't understand how the "real" `java.lang.Object` works. Does the JVM load a real `Object.class` file that was compiled from the OpenJDK's `Object.java`, or is the implementation built into the JVM? If a real classfile is used, how does that classfile specify no superclass? Do the compiler and JVM have special support for just that class somehow?